# Does Tensorflow rerun for each eval() call?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow and Python, I am doing the following sort of thing to understand Tensorflow and debug code by observing multiple variables at the end of a computation.

```
with tf.Session():
    print "var1 ="
    print (var1.eval({x:myInputs, y:myOutputs}))
    print "var2 ="
    print (var2.eval({x:myInputs, y:myOutputs}))
```

Does Tensorflow rerun the entire graph computation for each `eval()` call? Seems inefficient to rerun the entire graph just to print out one variable (tensor). If that is what is happening, is there a way to run the graph/process/eval once and then print out the values of each variable, without rerunning the entire graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call [`Tensor.eval()`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.eval), TensorFlow (i) works out what subgraph of the whole graph it needs to run to produce the value of that tensor, then (ii) runs that entire graph.

It is often more efficient to use [`Session.run()`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) to fetch the values of multiple tensors at once. For example, you could rewrite your code as follows to run the graph once:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    val1, val2 = sess.run([var1, var2], {x:myInputs, y:myOutputs})
    print "var1 =", val1
    print "var2 =", val2
```

Comment: what if i want to re-run the graph with sess.run ?