# Why are my examples and labels in the wrong order?

Tags: python, input, tensorflow, queue, shuffle

I'm trying trying to read some data in tensorflow, and then match it up with its labels. My setup is as follows:

- I have an array of english letters, `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ...`
- I have an array of "cyrillic" letters, `"a", "b", "w, "g", "d", ...`,
- I have an array of numbers, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...`

I want to create a queue of examples containing pairs between the first two arrays, like `["b", "b"], ["d", "g"], ["c", "w"], ...`. I also want a queue of the corresponding numbers to those pairs, which in this case would be `1, 3, 2, ...`

However, when I generate these queues, my examples and my numbers do not match up--for instance, a queue of `["b", "b"], ["d", "g"], ["c", "w"], ...` comes together with a label queue of `5, 0, 2, ...`.

What may be causing this? For testing, I have disabled all shuffling in queue/batch generation, but the problem persists.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf

from constants import FLAGS


letters_data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
cyrillic_letters_data = ["a", "b", "w", "g", "d", "e", "j", "v", "z", "i"]
numbers_data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]




def inputs(batch_size):
    # Get the letters and the labels
    (letters, labels) = _inputs(batch_size=batch_size)

    # Return the letters and the labels.
    return letters, labels


def read_letter(pairs_and_overlap_queue):
    # Read the letters, cyrillics, and numbers.
    letter = pairs_and_overlap_queue[0]
    cyrillic = pairs_and_overlap_queue[1]
    number = pairs_and_overlap_queue[2]

    # Do something with them
    # (doesn't matter what)
    letter = tf.substr(letter, 0, 1)
    cyrillic = tf.substr(cyrillic, 0, 1)
    number = tf.add(number, tf.constant(0))

    # Return them
    return letter, cyrillic, number


def _inputs(batch_size):
    # Get the input data
    letters = letters_data
    cyrillics = cyrillic_letters_data
    numbers = numbers_data


    # Create a queue containing the letters,
    # the cyrillics, and the numbers
    pairs_and_overlap_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([letters, cyrillics, numbers],
                                                            capacity=100000,
                                                            shuffle=False)

    # Perform some operations on each of those
    letter, cyrillic, number = read_letter(pairs_and_overlap_queue)

    # Combine the letters and cyrillics into one example
    combined_example = tf.stack([letter, cyrillic])


    # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
    min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
    min_queue_examples = int(FLAGS.NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN *
                             min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

    # Generate an example and label batch, and return it.
    return _generate_image_and_label_batch(example=combined_example, label=number,
                                           min_queue_examples=min_queue_examples,
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           shuffle=False)


def _generate_image_and_label_batch(example, label, min_queue_examples,
                                    batch_size, shuffle):

    # Create a queue that shuffles the examples, and then
    # read 'batch_size' examples + labels from the example queue.
    num_preprocess_threads = FLAGS.NUM_THREADS
    if shuffle:
        examples, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [example, label],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 6 * batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
    else:
        print("Not shuffling!")
        examples, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
            [example, label],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 6 * batch_size)

    # Return the examples and the labels batches.
    return examples, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])



lcs, nums = inputs(batch_size=3)



with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)


    for i in xrange(0, 5):
        my_lcs = lcs.eval()
        my_nums = nums.eval()

        print(str(my_lcs) + " --> " + str(my_nums))
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run [tv.eval()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval) twice, you actually run the graph twice, so you're mixing the lcs and nums from two different batchs, if you change your loop into the following you will pull both tensors during the same run of the graph:

```
    my_lcs, my_nums = sess.run([lcs, nums])

    print(str(my_lcs) + " --> " + str(my_nums))
```

This gives at my side:

```
[[b'g' b'j']
 [b'h' b'v']
 [b'i' b'z']] --> [6 7 8]
[[b'f' b'e']
 [b'g' b'j']
 [b'h' b'v']] --> [5 6 7]
[[b'e' b'd']
 [b'f' b'e']
 [b'g' b'j']] --> [4 5 6]
[[b'd' b'g']
 [b'e' b'd']
 [b'f' b'e']] --> [3 4 5]
[[b'c' b'w']
 [b'd' b'g']
 [b'e' b'd']] --> [2 3 4]
```

See also the following post:
 [Does Tensorflow rerun for each eval() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010987/does-tensorflow-rerun-for-each-eval-call)

Comment: Ugh, thanks so much. I really should've been able to find this, but I was sure the error was in my batch generation. Thank you!

Comment: nice investigation!